# finishedWithAuth method not gets called after authentication completion

Tags: ios, authentication, google-plus

I am doing Google+ Sign-In for iOS.

I am calling authentication method like

```
  [signIn authenticate];
```

I am not using signin butting.

In this case the following method not gets called after authentication

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error
```

Please let me know is there any way to handle the callback?

Comment: Is it a delegate method?

Comment: any solution for this ??? I have same issue..!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you go step by step what [*`Google+ Sign-In for iOS`*](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in) said? If yes, then you must missed a crucial step.

#### Step 5

In your `AppDelegate.m` file

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
```

#### Step 6

Call the `GPPURLHandler` URL handler from your app delegate's URL handler. This handler will properly handle the URL that your application receives at the end of the authentication process.

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

This method will invoke when your application will come back after Google+ OAuth, and immediately this will invoke

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error
```

method in you `viewController`

Try it now.

Comment: No Still the same issue :/

Comment: Vaibhav, did you ever find this solution?

Comment: In my app I had to implement both facebook and google signin and I implemented it successfully.

Comment: Hello vaibhav,

can guide me how you implement both facebook and google plus sign in both in application ?

Actually i have to do the same

- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation
{
}

and this method is not calling in my app

Comment: well, you need to create 2 URL Schemes in `Targets > Info > URL Types`
Here is a screenshot
http://s30.postimg.org/kl0tonou9/Screen_Shot_2015_03_17_at_12_42_47_PM.png

Comment: Please tell me after sharing how application will come back after Google + sharing.

Answer (score 0):

in sign in you need to do this in the viewDidLoad

```
signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, // defined in GTLPlusConstants.h
                 nil];
signIn.delegate = self;
```

then you need to do 1 of two options but not both.

option 1: add the class `GPPSignInButton`

or

option 2: add this `[signIn authenticate];` to some button

then use the auth like this

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error: (NSError *) error
{
if (error) {
    // Do some error handling here.
} else {
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
    [plusService setAuthorizer:auth];
    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                } else {
                    // Retrieve the display name and "about me" text
                    NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                             @"%@\n%@", person.displayName,
                                             person.identifier];

                }
            }];
    }
}
```

and your .h should be something like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
static NSString * const kClientId = @"yourappnumber.apps.googleusercontent.com";
@interface login : UIViewController<GPPSignInDelegate>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signInButton;
@end
```

Comment: what is `add the class GPPSignInButton` ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow this step as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signinButton;
```

Dont worry if you do not link it with any view, and just add it, it should work, If you have already done all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution for this in Swift 3.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if (url.absoluteString.range(of: "oauth2callback") != nil) {
       GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: nil)
    }
   return false
}
```